A pager UICollectionView with dynamic height
I’m trying to create a pager at the end of a scroll view. The pager should display different cells with varying text lengths. I’ve implemented this using a UICollectionView, enabled paging, and utilized a UICollectionViewFlowLayout.
However, I’m encountering issues: the collection view has an unusually long height (around 3000 pt), and paging isn’t working as expected.”
 private func setupLayout() {
    collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = .leastNonzeroMagnitude
    collectionViewLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
}

private func setupCollectionView() {
    wallCollectionView.register(cellOfType: SingleOverviewCell.self)
    wallCollectionView.delegate = self
    wallCollectionView.dataSource = self
    wallCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    wallCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
}

